# How do I remove shortcuts created by ARC Welder in Ubuntu GNOME applications menu

Tags: google-chrome-arc

In Ubuntu 15.04 I tried importing an ARC Welder application and it failed to actually create and run the app. However, it left two of the same shortcuts in my Applications menu in GNOME.

I've looked in `/usr/share/applications/` and in `~/.local/share/applications` and can't find any related shortcuts that are in reference to that app it tried to import.

Any other hints for removing these bogus shortcuts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found my answer.

Ran
`rm .local/share/applications/chrome-*.desktop`

Then just recreated the shortcuts that were valid and I needed

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach: find out which of the .desktop file is related to your non-starting app. I have been playing with an app named BankID, and this command highlights the related .desktop file:

```
grep -i bankid .local/share/applications/*
```